# Android License verification user flow implementation

Tags: android, licensing, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, user-experience

I have Implemented Licence Verification Library in my paid application with Guidelines provided on [Developers.android.com.](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html)
following is the user flow:

1. Users install/upgrade app.
2. They were asked for Contact permission(it is originally GET_ACCOUNTS permissionTo check if Google Account exists or not in a device) on start-up (Splash Screen) of the app.
3. Verify License for purchase.
4. if succeed then user able to use the app else they were presented with Licence verification failed Alert.

My problem is in step 2. Android 6.0 and above Users are actually getting confused that we are accessing their contacts.

so please suggest if I have implemented correct flow?

or is there any better way to handle this case?

or is there any to bypass the step 2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the working flow of this now, it is working fine in the live app from last 3 months with no issues.

I have resolved my problem of step 2 by modifying LicenceVerification Open Source Library. I have implemented suggested modification in **LicenseValidator.java** class

```
public void verify(PublicKey publicKey, int responseCode, String signedData, String signature) {
  -
}
```

In this method, i have added additional catch block for first `try.. catch()` block

```
catch (Exception e){ 
     handleInvalidResponse();
     return;
}
```

This hack resolved my problem and not asking CONTACT permission for Licence Verification anymore.